# Tkinter notebbok tabs different colours

Tags: python, tkinter

I have created a ttk Notebook with multiple tabs. Each of the tab contains data that user needs to enter.  What I would like to do is to change the colour of the tabs, based on a user button click.

Say, initially all the tabs are red. I have an update button for each tab, and when the user clicks this, the tab colour should change to green. I would like the user to know which all tabs are complete, and whch are not.

Is ther any way this is possible? I tried configuring the ttk.Style(), but it affects the entire notebook.

Comment: The tabs support the addition of images, so perhaps reconsider your design and indicate this with an icon on the tab.

Comment: yes, that could be a useful consideration :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simple to it by change the `color` of the `Button`

> Here is a simple example that can help you

```py
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
def click():
    btn.config(bg='green')
btn=Button(root,text='Update',bg='red',command=click)
btn.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The question was about the tab of a ttk Notebook widget. That widget doesn't use buttons.